Just reformatted the flash drive i used to install linux to zeroes, but how do I get it to work on windows as a normal flash drive now?
Basically, I orginically downloaded the linux installer onto a 32G flashdrive, which I used to put linux on my computer. I now need to use it to store some files from my windows computer, but when I tried to insert it into it, it kept saying that it was write-protected. So i put it back into my linux computer and reformatted it to be clear, and "compatible for any device." . It said it was 32G free on my linux computer, but now that I'm trying it with windows again it gives me an error window and says
d:/ directory name is invalid

So I decided maybe wiping it to zeroes would work, but given that will take like 2 hours, is there any better ways? If that doesn't work, is there any other method?

This isn't a Linux or Windows support site, but a Ubuntu Q&A support site. I see nothing in your question related to this site, so why ask here?  Your details highlight windows & only mention Linux. I suggest scanning https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

FYI:  Don't forget USB thumb-drives are cheap consumable electronics; made to cost. Each write potentially does them harm (they're a write few, read many intended media) and once a single bit (at a specific location) is no longer changeable you can experience what you describe... but this is a Ubuntu Q&A support site; not a electronics based site where Windows issues are resolved.     Also note you said formatted, you can format a file-system and not even impact the partition table which is where you're describing your problem - so consider all facts!

Your question doesn't even mention Ubuntu, nor give any product/release details.. only mentioning Linux & concentrating on Windows issues.  Please amend your question if it's incorrect.. Your fix is likely unrelated to format, but simply creating a new partition table using an appropriate tool.. You don't mention any specifics or tools in your question
